# Why is Filtered Statistics being ignored

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, statistics, sql-server-2014, cardinality

I'm having some problems understanding how the `Cardinality Estimator` uses filtered statistics.

When I run a query on `CE 120` it produces the expected estimate however when I switch to `CE 70` it appears to ignore the filtered stats.

Also, it appears that `CE 120` ignores the filtered stats if I don't use the actual stats column in the `WHERE` clause.

Below script to create and populate test table as well as create the filtered statistics.

```
/*
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64) 
    Jun  9 2015 12:06:16 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
*/

IF OBJECT_ID('Test_FS') IS NOT NULL  
  DROP TABLE Test_FS;

CREATE TABLE Test_FS (id int identity, a char(2), b char(2), c datetime
CONSTRAINT [Test_FS_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id ASC))

INSERT INTO Test_FS (a,b,c)
    VALUES 
       ('A1', 'B1', '2016-03-01'),
       ('A1', 'B1', '2016-09-01'),
       ('A1', 'B2', '2016-09-01'),
       ('A1', 'B2', '2016-09-01'),
       ('A1', 'B2', '2016-09-01'),
       ('A1', 'B2', '2016-09-01'),
       ('A1', 'B2', '2016-09-01'),
       ('A1', 'B2', '2016-09-01'),
       ('A2', 'B1', '2016-09-01'),
       ('A2', 'B1', '2016-09-01')

CREATE STATISTICS Test_FS_Filter_Stat 
ON Test_FS (c)
WHERE a = 'A1' 
      AND b = 'B1'
WITH FULLSCAN
```

First query is with `CE 120`

```
SELECT *
FROM Test_FS
WHERE a = 'A1'
      AND b = 'B1'
      AND c >= GETDATE()
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

And it behaves as one would expect: 1 row estimated / 1 row actual

> Worth noting that it did not auto-create stats for the individual
>   columns

### Question 1

When we run it with `CE 70`

```
SELECT *
FROM Test_FS
WHERE a = 'A1'
      AND b = 'B1'
      AND c >= GETDATE()
OPTION(RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 9481)
```

it ignores the filtered stats and estimates 2.88 rows.

> Please note that we now have auto-created stats for individual columns
>
> statistics_name
>   _WA_Sys_00000002_3587F3E0
>   _WA_Sys_00000003_3587F3E0
>   _WA_Sys_00000004_3587F3E0
>   Test_FS_Filter_Stat

Why does `CE 70` ignore the filtered stats?

I have a feeling it's `GETDATE()` that's causing it but I don't understand why and what can be done.

### Question 2

And now run a query with `CE 120` without condition on the filtered stat `target` column - only conditions on the filter columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM Test_FS
WHERE a = 'A1'
      AND b = 'B1'
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

This time it estimates 3.57771 rows and actually returns 2.

Why doesn't it use the filtered stats - total no of rows?

---

## Additional Info

I have looked at the stats loaded for above queries with following result:

Question 1:
CE 70 ignores the Filtered Stats when predicate is '**>=** GETDATE()' but uses it when '**=** GETDATE()' is specified.  If a date constant is specified CE 70 uses the Filtered Stats in both cases.

CE 120 uses the Filtered Stats in all above cases.

Question 2:
Both CE's totally ignore the Filtered Stats when no predicate is specified on 'c' which I find strange as that should certainly give them the best estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on your first question: `GETDATE` is non-deterministic function:

```
DECLARE @c DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT *
FROM Test_FS
WHERE a = 'A1' AND b = 'B1' AND c >= @c
OPTION(RECOMPILE)

SELECT *
FROM Test_FS
WHERE a = 'A1' AND b = 'B1' AND c >= @c
OPTION(RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 9481)
```

Execution plan from [*dbForge*](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/sql-query-profiler.html#header):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Devart. That’s where I came unstuck – this is what I found:  
a. If I only have the one condition 'c >= GETDATE()' the estimates are correct for both CE's.  
b. It's the same query but the estimate is correct for CE 120 and not for CE 70? Has GETDATE() changed behaviour?
Also, please see the additional info in the question

Comment: @carsten Cardinality Estimator partially documented, so nothing to say on your questions... :(